# Audit user without name

Tags: bug, review-audits

I'd like to report what seems to me a bug. Today I was doing some reviews and I've stumbled upon this audit:

[image: No name user]

If you look at the user, he is without name and without picture even if, when I opened the question, the user had both. This obviously make audits really easy to detect. Honestly, this is the first time that I notice this kind of behaviour (and I had quite a few audits recently) so it doesn't always happen. I only wanted to let you know that this is a thing.

Comment: Well you do have to be paying attention to notice that, and it doesn't tell you the correct answer.